# how to split javascript string, leaving just the characters

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I split a long string to an array of words.
I would like to ignore/remove all the non alphabethic characters.

For example:
If I have the next string: "free games @ somewhere, visit us. don't want to miss out?, then go ahead & visit us @ somewhere-to-download-from."

I would like it to be splitted to:
"free,games,somewhere,visit,us,don't,want,to,miss,out,then,go,ahead,visit,us,somewhere,to,down,load,from"

In the end I will have an array size 20 that on each cell it holds one word of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var chk = str.split(/[^a-z']+/i);
console.log(chk);
```

Comment: You don't have to escape `'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Javascript `split` function with a regular expression. Example:

```
var str = "free games @ somewhere, visit us. don't want to miss out?, then go ahead & visit us @ somewhere-to-download-from.";
alert(str.split(/[^a-z]+/i));
```

Comment: Also, I think you need to change it to `/[^a-z']+/i` (notice the `'`), because `don't` is getting split while it shouldn't.

Comment: How can I remove the "," in the result ? I've noticed that when I do alert(thearray); I get words splitted with "," which is added to the end of each word, how can I remove it?

Comment: It seems that the "." was replaced with "'", how do I change that it will remove "." too ?

Comment: When you convert array to string, Javascript adds "," after each element to beautify the result. Each array element does not have "," though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str = "free games @ somewhere, visit us. don't want to miss out?, then go ahead & visit us @ somewhere-to-download-from.";
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi," ").replace(/ {1,}/g," ").split(" ");
document.write(str);
```

Comment: You can simplify that chain of regular expressions with one simple `str.split(/[^a-z]+/i)`

Comment: I was taking multiple consecutive spaces into consideration, avoiding empty array elements from being returned by split().

Comment: That's why there's `+` in my expression, it does exactly that.

Comment: oh ... sorry. i didn't notice that immediately. you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function specialSplit(str){
    var reqArray = new Array();
    var len = str.length;
    var tempStr = "";
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(str[i].search(/[a-zA-Z']/)==0){
            tempStr = tempStr + str[i];
        }
        else if(tempStr.length > 0){
            reqArray.push(tempStr);
            tempStr = "";
        }
    }
    return reqArray;
}
```